# adding items to android listview

Tags: java, android

i Want to add items to listview from java class mainly

```html
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtMsg" />
```

My java code is

```html
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
```

I want to add into ListView(list) values which should display on phone and also should be clickable all code should be on java class

Comment: googling and learn about `listview adapter`

Answer (score 2):

```
 final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
        "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
        "Linux", "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux",
        "OS/2", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X", "Linux", "OS/2",
        "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile" };

    final ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
      list.add(values[i]);
    }
    final StableArrayAdapter adapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);



 private class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<String> objects) {
      super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
      for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
        mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
      }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
      String item = getItem(position);
      return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
      return true;
    }

  }
```

For item to be clickable in listview

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          int position, long id) {
        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        view.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(0)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                list.remove(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                view.setAlpha(1);
              }
            });
      }

    });
  }
```

Code taken From [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Comment: `+1` yupp, generally pain in the arse... no simple single-line solution

Answer (score 0):

This is two step process

Step 1 : Add `ListView` by Xml Layout or by Java code

```
ListView view=new ListView(Context);
```

Step2 : Create Adapter like `Array Adapter` and set the adapter on listview

```
String[] arr=new String[]{"a","b","c","d"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);
view.setAdapter(adapter);
```